# Roblox Lua error Value is not a valid member of Player, I don't try accessing that though

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a game on Roblox and a while ago I ran into an error, I couldn't find a fix and gave up, and I just started trying to fix it again. When I try to check if the player can afford to buy the item, I get the error Value is not a valid member of Player, here's my code from where the error is coming from

```
game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("Shop"):WaitForChild("UpgradeClicks").OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, price)
    if player.leaderstats.Views.Value <= price.Value then
        print("test")
    end
end)
```

Here's the code that happens when you press the button

```
local RE = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Shop.UpgradeClicks
local button = script.Parent
local price = script.Parent.Price
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    RE:FireServer(player, price)
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `FireServer()` the player that calls it is automatically added as the first argument in the server callback.

So the argument list that is arriving at the server is : player, player, intValue. That's why it is saying that Player.Value isn't valid.

Change your button code to not pass in the LocalPlayer.

```
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    RE:FireServer(price)
end)
```

Comment: When I do that it gets rid of the error but it doesn't print the message

Comment: MeDerp, there isn't enough information in your question for me to figure out why `player.leaderstats.Views.Value <= price.Value` is false. Now that the original error is fixed, perhaps you should try printing out more information to figure out what's going on, or ask another question with a more complete code sample.

Comment: Oh, I realized my mistake, I'm dumb, I did less than when I meant greater than. Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Try to call fireserver without putting in a player variable.

Comment: I think that player.leaderstats.Views.Value is what is causing the error so that would just break the script, what I mean is that if I remove the player part it would probably fix the error because it would break the script lol